# Clippath not working if created using Javascript but working perfectly if it is from HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am facing a issue in SVG clipping.I have one graph which need to be drawn dynamically from the javascript and the values is coming from the JSON. Now in one of the configuration I have to clip the curve if it is going out of range,otherwise I have to change the value range for both x and y axis to fit the curve in the graph window.
 I did some POC before implementation of the clipping functionality and I tried in conventional HTML tags and Its working fine. bellow is the code of the POC:

```
<svg>
   <defs>
    <clippath id="Clippath1">
        <rect id="Rect1" x="0" y="0" width="940.5" height="300">
        </rect>
    </clippath>
    <marker id="Marker1" viewbox="0 0 10 10" refx="5" refy="5" markerwidth="10" markerheight="10" orient="auto">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="1" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" fill="black">
        </circle>
    </marker>
</defs>
<g>
    <polyline points="0,0 140,125 160,140 180,220 220,240 300,280 400,450 500,500 900,900"
        style="fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-width: 5" clip-path="url(#clip)" stroke="blue"
        stroke-width="1" marker-start="url(#point)" marker-mid="url(#point)" marker-      end="url(#point)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

It is working fine. I have one marker to show the point and have one  inside the  tag and I have applied the clippath to my polyline.

Now in my project I need to perform the same thing from the javascript(creating all the tags) from the javascript. and It is not working.

```
    parentSVGGroup = _currTrendWin.getSVG();

    //Create a defs tag
    defs = PWC.HmiAC.svgPolyline.CreateSvgElement('defs', { 'id': 'drawableTrendArea_defs', 'appendTo': parentSVGGroup });

    //creating the  clippath
    clipPath = PWC.HmiAC.svgPolyline.CreateSvgElement('clippath', { 'id': 'drawableTrendArea_clippath', 'appendTo': defs });

    //creating the rectangle for the defining the drawable rectangle
    clipRect = PWC.HmiAC.svgPolyline.CreateSvgElement('rect',
                                                      { 'id': 'drawableTrendAreaRect',
                                                          'x': _currTrendWin.getRect().left,
                                                          'y': _currTrendWin.getRect().top,
                                                          'width': _currTrendWin.getRect().width,
                                                          'height': _currTrendWin.getRect().height,
                                                          'appendTo': clipPath
                                                      });

    markerConfig =
    {
        'id': 'point',
        'viewBox': '0 0 10 10',
        'refX': 5,
        'refY': 5,
        'markerWidth': 10,
        'markerHeight': 10,
        'orient': 'auto',
        'appendTo': defs
    };

    marker = PWC.HmiAC.svgPolyline.CreateSvgElement('marker', markerConfig);

    PointStyleConfig =
    {
        'cx': 5,
        'cy': 5,
        'r': 1,
        'stroke': 'red',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'fill': 'black',
        'appendTo': marker
    };
    pointStyle = PWC.HmiAC.svgPolyline.CreateSvgElement('circle', PointStyleConfig);


    polyLine = {
        'points': points.trim(),
        'id': _name,
        'fill': 'none',
        'stroke': 'blue',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'marker-start': 'url(#point)',
        'marker-mid': 'url(#point)',
        'marker-end': 'url(#point)',
        'clip-path': 'url(#drawableTrendArea_clippath)',
        'appendTo': parentSVGGroup
    };

    poly = document.getElementById(_name);
    if (poly) {
        poly.parentNode.removeChild(poly);
    }
    poly = PWC.HmiAC.svgPolyline.CreateSvgElement('polyline', polyLine);
```

This is the code stuff for the creation of the same logic from the javascript.But if I copy the generated html file from the browser and put the whole html tag into a new file it is working as expected.

Sorry I forgot to add that function..its bellow:

```
  _createSvgElement = function (type, attributes) {

  var svgElement = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, type),
  attr, value;
  if (attributes) {
        for (attr in attributes) {
            if (attr) {
                value = attributes[attr];

                if (attr === 'appendTo') {
                    value.appendChild(svgElement);
                }
                else {
                    svgElement.setAttributeNS(null, attr, value);
                }
            }
        }
     }
    return svgElement;
  };
```

could u ppl can help me out from the problem..

Thanks
Arijit

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that function..its bellow: Now It is updated. Robert Longson

Comment: Please come to the actual problem or the concepts!!!!

and to ans to your question _svgNS='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

Comment: I don't know what the problem is ;-( Perhaps if you created a jsfiddle to show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it is very late to the game. I am having the same issue, the problem seems to come from the fact that javascript/jquery both convert the elementname to all lower case and clippath actually needs to be clipPath.

I am currently trying to find a work around for this or if you did would you please share.

The PITA way I was able to get it to work was creating an HTML string and then using jquery to append the clipPaths to my defs section.

Not clean, not the way I would like to do it, but it got it done.